# requirejs Иницатор загрузки

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Есть куча модулей в JS приложении. Я заменил либу, моменял пути загрузки. Сложно отслеживать какой модуль грузит несуществущие файлы. В консоли ругается на require и анонимные функции. Как-то можно require заставить отображать какой модуль что грузит? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разве ошибки не пишут на какой строке они произошли?

Comment: добавил картинку дебаггер хрома не кажет

Comment: на сколько видно из картинки: не смог подгрузить файл `event.js`, проверьте есть ли он по этому пути? а так же можно просто полнотекстовым поиском поискать упоминание этого файла

Comment: Его и нету, но я не знаю какой модуль его грузит. В этом и суть вопроса.

Comment: да, я уже понял,  можно просто полнотекстовым поиском поискать упоминание этого файла в яваскриптовых файлах

Comment: и судя по всему модуль он написал: `collection/event`

Comment: requirejs не смог загрузить этот модуль

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36001/discussion-between-grundy-and-jk-action).